# Multiple ForeignCollection of same type in ORMLite

Tags: android, sqlite, ormlite

I'm using OrmLite on android for a structure simmilar to the following :

The Book class has a collection of primary BookArticle and a collection of secondary BookArticle :

```
    @DatabaseTable(tableName = "BookV1", daoClass = BookDaoImplV1.class)
public class Book implements IBook {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private String id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    private ForeignCollection<BookArticle> primaryArticles;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    private ForeignCollection<BookArticle> secondaryArticles;

    // constructor getters setters etc...

}
```

Then the BookArticle is declared as follow :

```
    @DatabaseTable(tableName = "BookArticleV1", daoClass = BookArticleDaoImplV1.class)
public class BookArticle implements IBookArticle {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private String id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String title;

    @DatabaseField
    private String summary;

    // for ORM mapping only
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnName = BOOK_FIELDNAME, index = true)
    private Book book;

    // constructor getters setters etc..

}
```

now saving the BookArticles and Book with DAO works fine however when I want to fetch my Book entity from database and access either primary or secondary articles (after a refresh() ) I have a problem because both collections hold ALL the articles (both primary and secondary) that have the book's id in their 'book' column.

Obviously I would need these primary and secondary articles to be separated when fetched from DB.

I would have expected "foreignFieldName" to be the answer to my problem.

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false, foreignFieldName = "secondaryArticles")
private ForeignCollection<BookArticle> secondaryArticles;
```

but apparently it does not work that way.

Is there a way for me to differenciate between these two collections ? 
Maybe using a simple annotation argument such as "owningFieldName" or similar that would get persisted in DB alongside the BookArticle data?

Many thanks for your help.

Alex

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem.

Not a real solution but you can try to use only one list with a boolean for switching between primary/secondary articles like this:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "BookV1", daoClass = BookDaoImplV1.class)
public class Book implements IBook {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private String id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    private ForeignCollection<BookArticle> articles;

    // constructor getters setters etc...

}
```

And then for the BookArticle class

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "BookArticleV1", daoClass = BookArticleDaoImplV1.class)
public class BookArticle implements IBookArticle {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private String id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String title;

    @DatabaseField
    private String summary;

    @DatabaseField
    private boolean isSecondary;

    // for ORM mapping only
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnName = BOOK_FIELDNAME, index = true)
    private Book book;

    // constructor getters setters etc..

}
```

Hoping to see a real answer

Answer (score 1):

if you want to add multible ForeignerCollections form the same typ to one class, you have to add 2 fields for ORM-Mapping in the BookArticle class and link this in the Book class to the ORM-Mapping fields.

e.g

**Book** class

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false, foreignFieldName = "primaryBook")
private ForeignCollection<BookArticle> primaryArticles;

@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false, foreignFieldName = "secondaryBook")
private ForeignCollection<BookArticle> secondaryArticles;
```

**BookArticle** class

```
// for ORM mapping primary Books
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnName = BOOK_FIELDNAME, index = true)
private Book primaryBook;

// for ORM mapping secondary Books
@DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnName = BOOK_FIELDNAME, index = true)
private Book secondaryBook;
```

When you call now bookDao.queryAll() and access the secondary Articles list, you will see the articles are correctly linked.

The disadvantage is, that you have 2 columes in the BookArticle Table for foreigner keys.

Greeting,
Codenix

Answer (score 0):

From official doc [Annotation Type ForeignCollectionField](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/ForeignCollectionField.html)

> Annotation that identifies a ForeignCollection field in a class that corresponds to objects in a foreign table that match the foreign-id of the current class.

Back to your code of `Book` class

```
@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
private ForeignCollection<BookArticle> primaryArticles;

@ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
private ForeignCollection<BookArticle> secondaryArticles;
```

When you refresh you collections, ormlite just does simple query

```
SELECT * FROM article WHERE book_id = 'id of book'
```

and after converts result into `BookArticle`collection

If you still want to have one-to-one relationship between book and article. Then simplest way to implement your initial requirement is next:

**Book** class

```
    @DatabaseTable(tableName = "BookV1", daoClass = BookDaoImplV1.class)
public class Book implements IBook {

    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private String id;

    @ForeignCollectionField(eager = false)
    private ForeignCollection<BookArticle> articles;

    public Collection<BookArticle> getArticles(boolean primary) throws SQLException {
        articles.refreshCollection();
        Collection<BookArticle> result = new ArrayList<BookArticle>();
        for (BookArticle article : articles) {
            if (article.isPrimary() == primary) result.add(article)
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

**BookArticle** class

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "BookArticleV1", daoClass = BookArticleDaoImplV1.class)
public class BookArticle implements IBookArticle {

    private static final String BOOK_FIELDNAME = "book_id";
    @DatabaseField(id = true)
    private String id;

    @DatabaseField
    private String title;

    @DatabaseField
    private String summary;

    @DatabaseField
    private boolean primary;

    public boolean isPrimary() {
        return primary;
    }

    // for ORM mapping only
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true, foreignAutoRefresh = true, columnName = BOOK_FIELDNAME, index = true)
    private Book book;

    // constructor getters setters etc..

}
```

To do article primary you need:

- link it to book;
- set primary property to `true`;
- update DAO;

To get book's primary articles :

- call `getArticles(true)` of needed book entity;

For use case 'secondary' use same steps with `false` value.